# Data Difference in GA Core Reporting API and GA dashboard

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I am using Core reporting API (V4) through java to extract data with custom dimension. 
There are two Scenarios. One in which i use two dimensions (pagePath and hostname) and in another i use just one dimension (pagePath only).
Issue is that i am observing difference in both requests. On using one dimension, data is exact copy of what I See on GA Dashboard. But on using two dimensions, This data i receive is not conforming with DA Dashboard.
Refer Code below -

```
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
dateRange.setStartDate("2016-08-01");
dateRange.setEndDate("2016-08-01");
Metric sessions = new Metric().setExpression("gaSmiley Tongueageviews").setAlias("PageViews");
Metric avgtime = new Metric().setExpression("ga:timeOnPage").setAlias("Time On Page");
List<Metric> list = new ArrayList<Metric>();
list.add(sessions);
list.add(avgtime);
Dimension dimension1 = new Dimension().setName("gaSmiley TongueagePath");
Dimension dimension2 = new Dimension().setName("ga:hostname");

List<Dimension> listd = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
listd.add(dimension1);
listd.add(dimension2); //---Error Occurs on Addition of this

List<DimensionFilter> filterList = new ArrayList<DimensionFilter>();
DimensionFilter dimFilter = new DimensionFilter().setDimensionName("gaSmiley TongueagePath").setOperator("REGEXP")
.setExpressions(Arrays.asList("53474130"));
filterList.add(dimFilter);
DimensionFilterClause clause = new DimensionFilterClause().setFilters(filterList);
clause.setFilters(filterList);

List<GetReportsResponse> responseList = new ArrayList<GetReportsResponse>();
String pageToken = "";
while(pageToken != null){
ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest().setViewId(VIEW_ID).setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
.setDimensions(listd).setMetrics(list).setDimensionFilterClauses(Arrays.asList(clause));
System.out.println(request);
if(pageToken != null && !pageToken.isEmpty()){
request.setPageToken(pageToken); }
ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
requests.add(request);
GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest().setReportRequests(requests);
GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();
System.out.println(response);
responseList.add(response);
pageToken = response.getReports().get(0).getNextPageToken();
break;
}
```

When ever I use "dimension2" in query Data comes out to be (3 records, whose data is different from what I see on dashboard)-

```
{
"dimensions": ["m.photos.timesofindia.com/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs-at-airport/articleshow/53474130.cms",
"m.photos.timesofindia.com"],
"metrics": [{
"values": ["12",
"19.0"]
}]
}{
"dimensions": ["m.photos.timesofindia.com/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs-at-airport/articleshow/53474130.cms",
"m.photos.timesofindia.com"],
"metrics": [{
"values": ["231",
"698.0"]
}]
}{
"dimensions": ["photogallery.indiatimes.com/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs-at-airport/articleshow/53474130.cms",
"photogallery.indiatimes.com"],
"metrics": [{
"values": ["168",
"648.0"]
}]
}
```

But When i re-run my code without the "hostname" dimension, Data i see is conforming with what is visible on dashboard. Response in this case is -

```
{
    "dimensions": ["m.photos.timesofindia.com/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs-at-airport/articleshow/53474130.cms"],
    "metrics": [{
        "values": ["217",
        "746.0"]
    }]
}{
    "dimensions": ["photogallery.indiatimes.com/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs-at-airport/articleshow/53474130.cms"],
    "metrics": [{
        "values": ["181",
        "2031.0"]
    }]
}
```

Current Core Reporting API version used is V4.
I have tried sampling also. But there was no difference is response.
I am seeing difference in data once i add "hostname" dimension.
Please help me out here.

Warm Regards,

Vibhav